# Trying to import data into R in a way that will allow anyone to access it when opening the markdown file/ accessing the html knit

Tags: r, dataframe, path

I am currently working on a coding project and I am running into trouble with how i Should import the data set. We are supposed to have it read in a way so that our instructor can access our markdown file and be able to import the data and run the code without changing file paths. I know about using relative file paths to make it accessible to anyone, however I don't know how to get around the /users/owner part of the file path. Any help would be greatly appreciated and if you have any further questions feel free to ask.

I've tried changing the working directory to a certain folder that both I and my instructor have named the same thing, however, like I said above, when I use read.csv to import the data frame I am still forced to use the /users/owner filepath which obviously is specific to my computer.

Answer (score 0):

I can understand your supervisor, I request the same from my students. My recommended solution is to put both data and R script (or the .Rmd file) in the same folder. Then one does not need to add a path in the `read.csv` (or similar) function.

If you use RStudio, move to the folder in the Files pane and then use the gear icon and select "Set as Working Directory".

[image]

Then send both files (.R or .Rmd) and the data to the supervisor, ideally as a zip file. The supervisor can then unpack it to an arbitrary folder and just double click to the .R/.Rmd file. The containing folder will then automatically become the working directory.

Other options are:

- to use a subfolder for the data or
- to put the data to a publicly readable internet location, e.g.
  Github and read it directly from there.

The last option requires of course that the data have a free license.